# (closed) discord.py imported file write NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

have problem when trying to import my commands from another file, it's not work, error is `NameError: name 'client' is not defined`, i find some info that it can be because you use client but in main file u used bot, but in maim file i used client too, and improted discord and commands in all files, here is all second file code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#hello
@client.command( aliases = ['hi', 'yo'] )

async def hello( ctx ):
    author = ctx.message.author

    await ctx.send( f' Hello { author.mention } !')
```

**Edited**

**I had to do it using cogs**

Comment: You haven't even defined `client`. Please research some basic python syntax like assigning variables.

Comment: @pigeonburger The code he is showing is the second file, main file has everything.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Well then he should include the main file, otherwise how are we supposed to help? I also don't see this file say anything about `client` being passed to the file he is showing, as well. It is still undefined.

Comment: @pigeonburger Exactly! He should do that.

Comment: @Luigi You need to show us the code in the second file as well. The main file you are talking about.

Comment: i figured out long time ago how to do it and edited this question

Answer (score 4):

Put

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")
```

after imports and:

```
client.run(TOKEN)
```

at the end.
This is just another question you ask. Please watch some tutorials about python and discordpy before you start trying to write your own code. This is basic mistake that you shouldn't ask for on SO.